# Adding the values entered in multiple textboxs and display the total count

Tags: c#

I had created a windows form.in that form there are 6 textbox's, I need to add the values entered in that 5textbox's and display in the 6th textbox in C#.net.

I've tried the following code:

```
txtbox6.Text = (Decimal.Parse(txtbox1.Text) + Decimal.Parse(txtbox2.Text)+
                (Decimal.Parse(txtbox3.Text)+(Decimal.Parse(txtbox4.Text)+   
                 (Decimal.Parse(txtbox5.Text)).ToString();
```

Comment: This is not working because of misplaced brackets.

Comment: you have more open than closed brackets

Comment: This won't even compile, brackets are mismatched.

Comment: `txtbox6.Text = (Decimal.Parse(txtbox1.Text) + Decimal.Parse(txtbox2.Text)+
                Decimal.Parse(txtbox3.Text)+Decimal.Parse(txtbox4.Text)+   
                 Decimal.Parse(txtbox5.Text)).ToString();` Try this

Comment: i'm not getting any error, when i enter the value and press tab key it is not displaying the total

Comment: Someone please direct this beginner to a basic tutorial link (I have no links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what if the text in one of the textboxes isn't a number? You could try something like this:

```
private Decimal GetNumberFromTextBox(TextBox txtbox)
{
    Decimal d;
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(txtbox.Text, out d))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number in " + txtbox.Name);
        // Instead you could return 0 here if that's what you want.
    }
    return d;
}

    textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(
            GetNumberFromTextBox(textBox1) +
            GetNumberFromTextBox(textBox2) +
            GetNumberFromTextBox(textBox3) +
            GetNumberFromTextBox(textBox4) +
            GetNumberFromTextBox(textBox5)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You were misplacing the brackets. Try the below code snippet.

```
        txtbox6.Text = (Decimal.Parse(txtbox1.Text) + Decimal.Parse(txtbox2.Text)+
        Decimal.Parse(txtbox3.Text)+Decimal.Parse(txtbox4.Text)+ 
        Decimal.Parse(txtbox5.Text)).ToString();
```